# How to loop through calendar with JQuery to fix accessibility issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I have a calendar that has already been built and now I need to fix accessibility issues with it. I am not supposed to change the underlying code if possible so I am trying to build a JQuery script onto of the project to fix the issues.

The issues are:

1. When a user tabs through the page they never get to the calendar.
2. If you add tabindex="0" through chrome inspector you can tab to the entries however instead going through each entry on each day and then looping to the next day, tab takes the user in a horizontal pattern where they tab to the first entry of each day in the first week, then the second entry of each day on the first week.

The calendar itself is quite tricky, the way it is created:

```
var Calendar = {

        init: function(day, eventid, message, isAdmin) {
            str.get_strings([
                { key: 'confirm_event', component: 'local_plugin' },
                { key: 'required' },
                { key: 'enter_all_required_fields', component: 'local_plugin' },
                { key: 'double_booking', component: 'local_plugin' },
                { key: 'events_not_found', component: 'local_plugin' },
            ]).then(function(all) {
                strings = all;
            });

            $('#local_plugin').fullCalendar({

                viewRender: function(view, element) {
                if (view.name == 'listMonth') {
                    var region = $('#filter_region').val();
                    var status = $('#filter_status').val();
                    var start = $('#local_plugin').fullCalendar("getView").start.format();
                    var end = $('#local_plugin').fullCalendar("getView").end.format();
                    $("#local_plugin .fc-view-container .fc-scroller").html('<div class="loader"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></div>').load(mdlcfg.wwwroot + '/local/local_plugin/calendar/ajax.php?action=get_events&view=table&region='+region+'&status='+status+'&start='+start+'&end='+end, function(e){ });
                    return;
                }
            },
```

When the html page is loaded there is no calendar, just a call to Calendar.init(). All the page has is an empty div with id='#local_plugin'. When this calendar object is called it seems to generate all relevant html, css and js to build the calendar. I am not going to go through it because there are thousands of lines it calls upon.

The html this Calendar.init() produces looks like this:

```
<tbody class="fc-body">
   <tr>
      <td class="fc-widget-content">
         <div class="fc-scroller fc-day-grid-container" style="overflow: hidden; height: 813px;">
            <div class="fc-day-grid fc-unselectable">
               <div class="fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content fc-rigid" style="height: 140px;">
                  <div class="fc-bg">
                     <table>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sun fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-25"></td>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-26"></td>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-tue fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-27"></td>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-wed fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-28"></td>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2018-03-01"></td>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2018-03-02"></td>
                              <td class="fc-day fc-widget-content fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2018-03-03"></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-content-skeleton">
                     <table>
                        <thead>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-sun fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-25"><span class="fc-day-number">25</span></td>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-mon fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-26"><span class="fc-day-number">26</span></td>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-tue fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-27"><span class="fc-day-number">27</span></td>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-wed fc-other-month fc-past" data-date="2018-02-28"><span class="fc-day-number">28</span></td>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2018-03-01"><span class="fc-day-number">1</span></td>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-fri fc-past" data-date="2018-03-02"><span class="fc-day-number">2</span></td>
                              <td class="fc-day-top fc-sat fc-past" data-date="2018-03-03"><span class="fc-day-number">3</span></td>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-event-container">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="872" data-event-type="off_road_lesson">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">4:01a</span> <span class="fc-title">Secondary College</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                              <td class="fc-event-container">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="119" data-event-type="in_class_session">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">4a</span> <span class="fc-title">Test Booking</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                              <td class="fc-event-container" rowspan="4">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="889" data-event-type="on_road_lesson">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">9:50p</span> <span class="fc-title">Lesson: 777</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                              <td class="fc-event-container">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="201" data-event-type="in_class_session">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">11:44a</span> <span class="fc-title">Testing End Can't Be Before Start</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                              <td rowspan="4"></td>
                              <td rowspan="4"></td>
                              <td rowspan="4"></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-event-container">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="873" data-event-type="off_road_lesson">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">4:01a</span> <span class="fc-title">Secondary College</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                              <td class="fc-event-container" rowspan="3">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="876" data-event-type="off_road_lesson">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">4:11a</span> <span class="fc-title">College</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                              <td class="fc-event-container" rowspan="3">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="118" data-event-type="in_class_session">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">2p</span> <span class="fc-title">Booking Test</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-event-container">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="874" data-event-type="off_road_lesson">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">4:01a</span> <span class="fc-title">Secondary College</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-event-container">
                                 <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end" data-event-id="875" data-event-type="off_road_lesson">
                                    <div class="fc-content"><span class="fc-time">4:01a</span> <span class="fc-title">Secondary College</span></div>
                                 </a>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-bgevent-skeleton">
                     <table>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td class="fc-nonbusiness fc-bgevent" colspan="1"></td>
                              <td colspan="6"></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="fc-bgevent-skeleton">
                     <table>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td colspan="6"></td>
                              <td class="fc-nonbusiness fc-bgevent" colspan="1"></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

I need to add a little js at the bottom of the calendar page to add tabindex to all the days, dates and entries. Not only this, the tab index also needs to have order such that tab will loop a user through each day before moving to the next day. After researching the issue I assume I need to use the .each() function however when briefly testing I can't even get an alert to work:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.fc-body').children('.fc-row').each(function () {
            alert('test');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I assume this is not working as $(document).ready is not necessarily waiting for the Calendar.init() to run. Anyway I can delay the JS to run after the calendar has been created and also after I have done this how would I go about implementing the solution? I suspect this is quite an audacious task.

Comment: $('.fc-body').children('.fc-row') looks for any children of 'fc-body' with the class 'fc-row'. However, the child of your 'fc-body' is just a '<tr>'. '.children' doesn't look inside any deeper than that.